# Using the duration of mouse press for scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I coded this:

```js
$("#scroll-to-left-button").on("mousedown", function() {
  var x = $("#scroll-area").scrollLeft();
  $("#scroll-area").scrollLeft(x - 10);
});


$("#scroll-to-right-button").on("mousedown", function() {
  var x = $("#scroll-area").scrollLeft();
  $("#scroll-area").scrollLeft(x + 10);
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#scroll-area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="scroll-area">
    <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="scroll-to-left-button">Scroll to left</button>
<button id="scroll-to-right-button">Scroll to right</button>
```

You need to click the buttons pretty often to navigate through this container. Is there a way to let it based on the duration of the mouse press? Like if you keep the mouse pressed, it continues constantly scrolling? And if you stop, it stops.

Would be happy if someone could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Also your code was a bit wet, so I refactored it a bit. You only need one mousedown event listener.

```js
let interval;

$('.scroll-btn').on('mousedown', ({ target }) => {
    const type = $(target).attr('id');

    interval = setInterval(() => {
        var x = $('#scroll-area').scrollLeft();
        $('#scroll-area').scrollLeft(type === 'left' ? x - 10 : x + 10);
    }, 50);
});

$('.scroll-btn').on('mouseout mouseup', () => clearInterval(interval));
```

```css
#container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

#scroll-area {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="scroll-area">
        <div id="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
            sed diam voluptua.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="left" class="scroll-btn">Scroll Left</button>
<button id="right" class="scroll-btn">Scroll Right</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just found a mistake: If you start pressing for example "Scroll Right" and move your cursor while pressing out of the document area, the function gets destroyed. Should there be a mouseup trigger? How is it possible to fix that?

Comment: @Anna_B Nice catch! I just edited my answer to fix the bug. Just switched `mouseup` to `mouseout`

Comment: Thank you so much! I posted here an additional question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71722861/horizontal-scroll-areas-with-buttons-and-gradients – Do you think you can help me with that as well? I would be super happy!

Comment: @Anna_B Checking it out :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, the mousedown and mouseup make a good pair, although you have used only mousedown :)

Here's a sample how it could be done.

Note that there're couple other things that could be done to this code for it to look nicer:

- `.on(...` is not probably needed, you could just write it as `.mousedown(...`
- the code for the right and left buttons look really similar, you could unite these blocks in one and distinguish by an additional attrubute (let's say like `move="10"` for the right button and `move="-10"` for the left one, and then just getting this value in order to add it to `scrollLeft`)

```js
var tmr;

$(".scroll-button").mousedown(function() {
    //let's setup the timer here...
   move = +$(this).attr("move");
   tmr = setInterval(function(){
       $("#scroll-area")[0].scrollLeft+=move;
   }, 250)
});

$(".scroll-button").mouseup(function() {
    // and destroy the timer here
   clearInterval(tmr);
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#scroll-area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="scroll-area">
    <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="scroll-button" move="-10">Scroll to left</button>
<button class="scroll-button" move="10">Scroll to right</button>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! The preview unfortunately doesn't show the area completely. I copied it here: https://jsfiddle.net/wz0um5g9/ – Unfortunately, nothing happens if I click the buttons

Comment: @Anna how is that? look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkXWN.gif

Comment: Why do you have `right_timer` and `left_timer`? We only need one variable to hold the interval, especially because only one button can be held down at a time, and the interval is cleared right when `mouseup` occurs.

Comment: @mstephen19 yeah that sounds right