# Horizontal scroll areas with buttons and gradients

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, horizontal-scrolling

This is my code so far:

```js
// Show and hide gradients

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".scroll-area").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this)[0].scrollWidth <= $(this)[0].clientWidth) {
      $(this).closest(".container").find(".left").css("display", "none");
      $(this).closest(".container").find(".right").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $(this).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this)[0].scrollWidth > $(this)[0].clientWidth) {
          if ($(this).scrollLeft() > 0) {
            $(this).closest(".container").find(".left").css("display", "block");
          }

          if ($(this).scrollLeft() == 0) {
            $(this).closest(".container").find(".left").css("display", "none");
          }

          var fullWidth = $(this)[0].scrollWidth - $(this)[0].offsetWidth - 1;

          if ($(this).scrollLeft() >= fullWidth) {
            $(this).closest(".container").find(".right").css("display", "none");
          }

          if ($(this).scrollLeft() < fullWidth) {
            $(this).closest(".container").find(".right").css("display", "block");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});


// Scroll buttons

let interval;

$('.scroll-btn').on('mousedown', ({
  target
}) => {
  const type = $(target).attr('id');

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    var x = $('#a').scrollLeft();
    $('#a').scrollLeft(type === 'left-arrow' ? x - 10 : x + 10);
  }, 50);
});

$('.scroll-btn').on('mouseup', () => clearInterval(interval));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.scroll-area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
}

.left {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.right {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  right: 0;
}

.arrow {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 0;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: 0;
}

.left-arrow div,
.right-arrow div {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="x" class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>

  <div class="arrow left-arrow">
    <div class="scroll-btn" id="left-arrow">
      <</div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow right-arrow">
      <div class="scroll-btn" id="right-arrow">></div>
    </div>

    <div id="a" class="scroll-area">
      <div class="text">Scroll to right. The gradients and arrows should appear and disappear based on the scroll position. It should work with more than one container. Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The needs are:

1. The arrows should appear and disappear in the same way like the gradients.
2. If there is not enough text to cause a scrollable area, there should be no gradient and now arrow.
3. There should be more than one container in the end.

Can somebody help me to do that? I would be super thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your arrows inside the left/right gradient `div`s.  That way they will show/hide same way as the gradients.

***EDIT***

I cleaned up the code a bit since the original answer was kinda messy. (or 'weird' as mstephen19 put it :)).

```js
// Show gradient and left/right arrows only if scrollable
$(".scroll-area").each((i, el) => {
  $(el).parent().find(".right")[el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth ? "show" : "hide"]();
});

// Show/hide gradient and arrows on scroll
$('.scroll-area').scroll((e) => {
  const fullWidth = $(e.target)[0].scrollWidth - $(e.target)[0].offsetWidth - 1;
  const left = $(e.target).scrollLeft()

  $(e.target).parent().find(".left, .left-arrow")[left > 0 ? "show" : "hide"]();
  $(e.target).parent().find(".right, .right-arrow")[left < fullWidth ? "show" : "hide"]();
});

// Scroll on left/right arrow mouse down
let intervalId;
$(".left-arrow, .right-arrow").on("mousedown", (e) => {
  const scroll = $(e.target).closest(".container").find(".scroll-area");
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    const left = scroll.scrollLeft();
    scroll.scrollLeft(e.target.classList.contains("left-arrow") ? left - 10 : left + 10);
  }, 50);
}).on("mouseup mouseleave", () => {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.scroll-area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.left {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.right {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 40px
}

.left-arrow {
  display: none;
  left: -25px;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    
    <div class="left-arrow">&lt;</div>
    <div class="right-arrow">&gt;</div>

    <div class="scroll-area">
      <div class="text">Scroll to right. The gradients and arrows should appear and disappear based on the scroll position. It should work with more than one container. Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left"><span class="left-arrow">&lt;</span></div>
    <div class="right"><span class="right-arrow">&gt;</span></div>

    <div class="scroll-area">
      <div class="text">No scroll.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this doesn't help me. The arrows must overlap like in my design. And if you click an arrow, the area should scroll in the way it works in my example.

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I don't understand what you are after this time.  "Arrows must overlap"?  Not sure what you mean.  And clicking the arrows in your example doesn't do anything.  Do you want to scroll upon clicking the arrows?

Comment: Does nothing happen if you scroll the right arrow in my example? Yes, it should scroll. And it does with my machine. And overlap from a design view. Like the arrow should be above and overlap the scroll area.

Comment: Hi @Anna_B, your arrows doesn't do anything on my end unfortunately.  Please see my updated answer tho.  Hopefully it is what you are looking for or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Tim, your code is weird man.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! Would it be possible to exclude the arrows from the gradient? They shouldn't be nested.

Comment: @Anna_B, sure, I have updated my answer so it looks more like your example.

Comment: @Tim I posted here an additional question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71865130/bugfixing-of-horizontal-scroll-area-with-gradients-and-arrows – Do you think you could help with that as well? <3

Answer (score 0):

Some things about your code:

1. Your original code would not work with multiple containers, because you had a hardcoded `#a` ID in the interval code. You should really only have IDs on one element ideally, anyways (they're unique identifiers, while classes can be placed on multiple elements). The `.scroll-area` element should be found based on the target clicked.
2. You should combine your gradient and arrow elements into one element. By that, I mean making the `div` in which the arrow lives should be a child of the gradient `div`. Why manage them both separately?
3. Use class adding/removing/toggling instead of directly setting the CSS. Remember - when you find yourself writing the same code multiple times, it usually means there is a way to condense it down and make your code more dry and easier to understand + read.
4. Don't use the literal `<` and `>` symbols, as it can confuse some browsers. Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead.
5. Rather than toggling `display` to `none` and `block`, it's better to use `visibility` in this specific case. In my example, we use `opacity` for a fun fading effect.
6. Don't forget to listen for both `mouseup mouseout` events :)

Here is the working solution. I've refactored the code a bit:

```js
let interval;

$('.arrow').on('mousedown', ({ target }) => {
    const type = target.classList[1];

    const scrollArea = $(target).parent().find('.scroll-area');
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        const prev = scrollArea.scrollLeft();
        scrollArea.scrollLeft(type === 'left-arrow' ? prev - 10 : prev + 10);
    }, 50);
});

$('.arrow').on('mouseup mouseout', () => clearInterval(interval));

$('.scroll-area').on('scroll', ({ target }) => {
    const left = $(target).parent().find('.left-arrow');
    const right = $(target).parent().find('.right-arrow');

    const scroll = $(target).scrollLeft();

    const fullWidth = $(target)[0].scrollWidth - $(target)[0].offsetWidth;

    if (scroll === 0) left.addClass('hide');
    else left.removeClass('hide');

    if (scroll > fullWidth) right.addClass('hide');
    else right.removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 550px;
    height: 80px;
    background: grey;
    position: relative;
}

.right-arrow,
.left-arrow {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.scroll-area {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}

.right-arrow {
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
    left: 500px;
}

.left-arrow {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
    left: 0px;
}

.scroll-btn {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="arrow left-arrow">
        <div class="scroll-btn" id="left-arrow">&lt;</div>
    </div>

    <div class="arrow right-arrow">
        <div class="scroll-btn" id="right-arrow">&gt;</div>
    </div>

    <div class="scroll-area">
        <div class="text">
            Scroll to right. The gradients and arrows should appear and disappear based on the scroll position. It should work with more than one
            container. Lorem ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: If you don't like the fade effect, remove the `transition: all 0.2s linear;` part of the CSS, and switch `.hide`'s `opacity: 0` to `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you! It works, buuuut I would need the arrows excluded from the gradients. Do you think you can edit your answer like that? I would be super happy! <3

Comment: @Anna_B What do you mean? You mean that the arrows should always be visible? Or that the arrows must not be children of the gradient `div` elements?

Comment: They shouldn't be children. But still should disappear if scrolled to one end.